# How to solve this problem "unity android gradle build failed"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLXbx.png)

I am trying to release a game for Android, but I am getting these errors. I would be very happy if you can help me resolve these.

Comment: Please add the full error and stderr output from the editor log to your question as text.

Comment: I can't fit the error text

Answer (score 0):

This is my full method of fixing these errors as they are very common for me and many other people.
This did come from my solution in Unity Forums (here’s the link): https://forum.unity.com/threads/man-its-a-hell-in-building-android-unity-2020-3-19f1.1209706/#post-8187237

But here’s the main fix:

Firstly uninstall and re-install the current unity editor completely by deleting it from ProgramFiles/Unity/Hub/Editor/YOUR_EDITOR_VERSION. Next I re-installed the same editor (MAKE SURE YOU SELECT ANDROID SDK, NDK AND JDK). Then delete your .gradle folder in Users/YOUR_NAME. I then deleted my Plugins folder in the assets of my project. Finally set JAVA_HOME variable to your unity editor OpenJDK location like this: ProgramFiles/Unity/Hub/Editor/YOUR_EDITOR_VERSION/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK
After that restart your PC and run unity and when you build there should be no errors!

Comment: still not fixed, I keep getting the same error. Thanks for your effort anyway.

Comment: Are you sure you restarted your computer? Because you can only set environment / system variables and then restart it.